Как обновить графический интерфейс из другого потока?
Какой самый простой способ обновить один объект Label из другого Thread?

У меня запущен Form в thread1 и с этого момента я начинаю другой поток thread2.

Пока в thread2 идет обработка некоторых файлов, я хотел бы обновить информацию Label в Form о текущем статусе работы thread2.


Как я могу это сделать?
